# mod_rewriter, error with redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with mod_rewrite rule in apache.

This module is installed and working, i have tested it with wordpress permanent links and it works fine.

Now i have another website where want to apply the url change.

my main domain : www.mydomain.com
the current adress for my posts.   www.mydomain.com/post.php?id=111
i need to change this adress to:

www.mydoman.com/year/month/post title here

EDIT!
For example this works great for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^/.&]+)/?$ 
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ /%1?  [NS,R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&redirect=no [NS,QSA]
```

but it only show www.mydomain.com/postID

**Please any kind of help ?**

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add the ID to your URL, there's just no other simple way to do it:

```
URL = www.mydoman.com/year/month/post-title/111

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/.*/.*/([0-9]*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry as iam not good at mod_rewriting, please let me know what should i paste at my .httacess file ? only 
RewriteRule ^.*/.*/.*/([0-9]*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
? thank you

Comment: You also need `RewriteEngine On`, but yes, just those two lines will forward requests for URLs like the one in the answer onto you `post.php` page.

Comment: i have pasted this: 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/.*/.*/([0-9]*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
but nothing changed!! why ?

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: i  am clicking on my posts, and their url isnt changed.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's possible using RewriteRules. They can't change the links in your HTML. Have a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information

Comment: so how wordpress works ? all wordpress links are changed. please can i know how to use it ? i need that links will be the same i writed up

Comment: You just need to change the URLs wherever you output them as a link (`<a>` tag) in your HTML/PHP files. The `RewriteRule` then forwards that otherwise non-existent URL to your `post.php` file (where you have the post's ID in `$_GET['id']`), and go from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4402/discussion-between-meo-and-clive)

Comment: i am there wiating for you :)